# How is this code working? Here the class name is used as a datatype in its own implementation

Tags: c#

```
public class Node
{
    public int Value { get; set; }
    public Node Next { get; set; }
}
```

I am a complete beginner in programming. I decided to learn C# as my first programming language. I came across this code.

How is 'Node' defined as the datatype for Next? It is confusing me a lot.

Comment: Because a class is allowed to have an instance of itself as one of its properties.

Comment: This looks like a standard linked-list implementation. `Next` points to the next element in the list. Imagine people standing in line and each Person is pointing to the Person next to them.

Comment: Put the cursor inside Node, hit F12 and see where it jumps to. 
If it's not in a `System` or `Microsoft` namespace then it;'s not part of the framework

Answer (score 1):

This is a good question to ask as you're learning about C#. The key is that there are two kinds of types in C#: "value" types and "reference" types. See [this question and its answers for more details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5057267/what-is-the-difference-between-a-reference-type-and-value-type-in-c).

Because `Node` is declared as a `class`, that means it is a reference type.
If you make a variable with a reference type, then that variable doesn't hold the data directly; instead, it holds a *reference that can point to* the data. By default, references have the special value `null`, which means they don't point to anything. When you assign a variable e.g. `myNode.Next = someOtherNode`, you don't copy the entirety of `someOtherNode` to the `Next` property; you just copy a reference to `someOtherNode` into the property.

So by the `Node` class itself having a `Node` property, a `Node` object doesn't actually contain another `Node` object. The first object contains a *reference* to the second object. This allows one node to point to another node, which can then point to another node, and so on. A collection of nodes organized this way is called a *linked list*; in this case, it's a linked list of `int` (32-bit integer) values.

If `Node` were a value type (declared as a `struct` instead of a `class`), then there would indeed be a problem. Value type variables contain the data directly, so you cannot have an instance of a value type which contains another instance of that same value type.

Answer (score 1):

Like other answers, this class represents a node for a linked list.  In this case the `Node` can point to another instance of Node.

```
Node 
{
   int Value = 1;
   Node Next =============>  Node {
}                                   int Value = 2;
                                    Node Next ===========> Node {
                                  }                                int Value = 3;
                                                                   Node Next =======> null
                                                                 }
```

You don't usually come across classes having references to themselves like `Node`.

Comment: Though, I would disagree about your last sentence. They can be pretty usual, especially if you have classes that represent your standard database for your company's data. An employee has a manager, which is another employee, etc.

Comment: @Pac0 That's why I qualified that sentence with the word "usually".  Still I think the number of classes referencing themselves like `Node` and Employee entity is far less.

Answer (score 0):

This is called a linked list, an example of a recursive data structure. This can easily be instantiated in C# because the recursion can be ended by letting the last node in the list have a null value for the Next property.

Answer (score 0):

That looks like a class defining a node in a singly linked list that stores integer values. Remember a class is just a definition of the shape of an object.  This may work like:

var node1 = new Node { Value=1} ;
node1.Node = new Node { Value=2};